# How can the web3 library be imported in a web application?

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs

During the compilation of my JS code I used the statement `Web3 = require('web3')` for importing the web3 library. But since the `require` function doesn't work in a web application, I would like to know how it can be done.
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44925646/why-is-require-module-in-javascript-not-able-to-import-the-fs-library/44925882#44925882)

Comment: Answer is in this question here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/66396/9815

Answer (score 11, accepted):

by web application you mean HTML/..

download web3js form [github](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/tree/0.20.7/dist) repo.

you could load it as normal js file using

```
<script src="web3js_path"></script>
```

e.g

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="web3.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">  if(typeof window.web3 !== "undefined" && typeof window.web3.currentProvider !== "undefined") {
        var web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
      } else {
        var web3 = new Web3();
      }
</script>
```

Comment: Should `metamask` be on on the browser because of `window.web3`?

Comment: The link to github in this answer is dead

Comment: @JesseBusman for the old lib try : https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/tree/0.20.7/dist

Answer (score 1):

You can add it to your client code using package managers like [bower](https://bower.io/):

```
bower install web3
```

or [Component](http://component.github.io/)

```
component install ethereum/web3.js
```

or simply include distributed and minified library [web3.min.js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/tree/develop/dist) in your html file:

```
<script src="PATH/web3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The current answers detail how to include web3.js - a standalone Javascript file.

Your question implies that you are using a package manager - [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) perhaps?

To pull in `require`d packages, and utilise them within the browser you can utilise a tool like [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/).

Your question is however lacking in details so I am just making assumptions..