# How to use Web3js from Obj-C

Tags: web3js, ios

I'm totally new to JS. I'm developing on ios and we need to use Web3js in our program. It's ok to call js function in obj-c. However, I use 'require' to import Web3js modules, it throws 'ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require'. I know it's about Nodejs runtime. I also tried to use browserify to build web3js ,but it showed some "Cannot find module ''web-core" from xxxx" error.

here is my code.
obj-c code:

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bridge/src/index" ofType:@"js"];
jsFunc = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

JSContext* jsContext = [[JSContext alloc] init];
[jsContext evaluateScript:jsFunc];
JSValue* func = jsContext[@"getAddress"];
JSValue* = [func2 callWithArguments:@[@"0x8730f6ad1c0d387644590966bdbfedba44fe250118df0f97f11190ad5727b312"]];
```

js:

```
function getAddress(prvKey)
{
  try{
      var Web3 = require('../../3rd_party/web3.js-1.0.0');     
      var web3 = new Web3();
      return web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(prvKey);
     }
  catch (e)
  {
      return e;
  }
}
```

I know webView is another way to invoke js functions. It's more strange. I wrote the followings in a html which is invoked by my webView.

```
function getAddress(prvkey)
{
   var web3 = new Web3();
   return prvkey;
   ...
}
```

It returns an empty string even if I use try-catch. I totally have no idea how to troubleshoot.

Anyone could help me how to use Web3js from obj-c?

Many thanks.

Comment: BTW, it doesn't work for me, https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19483/how-can-the-web3-library-be-imported-in-a-web-application/19493

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Browserify to package all modules and then used webView to call the js functions.

here is my js file, index.js

```
"use strict"
let Web3 = require('web3.js');
window.Web3 = Web3;
```

and then use Broswerify to pack

```
browserify index.js -o web3.js
```

my html,

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="web3.js"></script>   
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getAddress(prvkey)
        {
            try
            {
                var web3 = new Web3();
                var account  = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(prvkey);
                return account.address;
            }
            catch (e)
            {
                return e;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a library for IOS :
[web3Js in Swift](https://github.com/BANKEX/web3swift)

You can use this library in Objective-C as well.