# Web3.js browser version only

Tags: web3js, javascript, nodejs

I want to create a simple page to interact with my deployed contract. I don't want to use Node.js. I want to use html + web3.js browser version. I got a link: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/tree/develop/dist

But the above link contains web3.js files that contains "require" keyword which cannot run in browser. I want browser version of web3.js.

Comment: The files you find there are the correct ones to use in the browser. If you're encountering some sort of error when you try, please share your code and the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 5):

For web3.js 1.0, I got it working like this:

In head:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js@1.0.0-beta.34/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
```

Then get a reference to it:

```
<script>
var web3js = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://testnet-rpc.gochain.io'));
</script>
```

And use it like this:

```
var contract = new web3js.eth.Contract(abi, address);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Why instantiating `Web3` within `Web3`? (`new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8545'))`)

Answer (score 1):

Use script tag to include web3.js in any html:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
```

Following code snippet will check for any injected web3.js instance(Metamask etc). if not then will fallback to local geth node or infura endpoints.

```js
function initweb3 () {   
    if(type of web3 !== 'undefined') {
        // Use injected web3
        web3js = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
        /* Fallback to local node or remote node               
        by default local HTTP-RPC server exposes port 8545.
        you can use Infura Node Urls also
        'https://ropsten.infura.io/<API KEy>'*/    
        web3js = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8545'));
    }
}
                 
// You should initialize web3 instance after window load event has fired to avoid any race condition.               
window.addEventListener('load',initweb3);
```

Comment: Throws "cb" is not defined error. I am not using node.js

Comment: cb here is notation for callback function, after onLoad event, which function you want to call, put that function in place of "cb"

Comment: Made modifications in code.

Comment: HOw do I use es6 module import?

Comment: Why instantiating `Web3` within `Web3`? (`new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8545'))`)