# How to print web3.eth.<function> output on html page?

Tags: web3js, nodejs

I am trying to print `web3.eth.<function> output` on a html page, but I cannot print it.

I have followed this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/19494/4575). My geth-node is running on `--rpcport 8545`.

Let's see simple example to print `blockNumber`.

**example.html**

```
<html>
  <head>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
      window.addEventListener('load', function() {
          var web3 = window.web3 ;
          if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
          web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
          } else {
          // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
          web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
          }
      });

      function getblocknumber() {
          //alert()
           //document.getElementById("status").innerHTML =  web3.version.api //works, returns: 0.20.3
          document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = web3.eth.blockNumber; //returns empty string
    }
   </script>        
 </head>
<body>
 <p>Get Block Number:</p> <button onclick="getblocknumber()">Get Block Number </button>
 <p id="status"></p>
 </body>
</html>
```

---

**myserver.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

app.use(express.static('.'));

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

})
```

---

To run:

```
$ node myserver.js
Example app listening at http://:::8081
```

To open; from browser: `http://localhost:8081/example.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
web3.eth.getBlockNumber(function (err, blockNumber) {
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = blockNumber;
});
```

Comment: Could I also use same approach for events?

Comment: If you mean events emitted from your smart contract, you'd do something similar. (You'd subscribe and then update your UI in the callback.)

Comment: Yes, I meant events emitted from your smart contract.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of web3 are you using? If you are using v1.0.0 you are using it incorrectly...

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#getblocknumber

Comment: Its `v0.20.3` ...