# Where Do I Find web3.min.js for Beta 55?

Tags: web3js, web3js-v1.x

There is this issue on github (among several other duplicate complaints): https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/2623.

There is also this stack question: [How can the web3 library be imported in a web application?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19483/how-can-the-web3-library-be-imported-in-a-web-application). Unfortunately, this answer only provides how to inject beta 37 (which for whatever reason is also now version 1.2). Beta 37 doesn't work for what I am doing, I need Beta 55. How do I acquire this version in a minified form for browser injection?

Edit: Link to github for Beta 55 branch is dead. https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/tree/v1.0.0-beta.55/dist

Comment: I recommend that you do the opposite, i.e., adjust your code to work with beta 37. That's because beta 37 is in fact the currently most stable version of web3.js.

Comment: But I don't agree and want Beta 55. How do I get it? And why should I prevented from testing and verifying your opinion? Also, Beta 55 will be compatible with v2. There's no point to staying in the past if what I have is working on Beta 55 and not on 37.

Comment: "And why should I prevented from testing and verifying your opinion?" - You shouldn't. Feel free to do that (testing and verifying my opinion).

Comment: My frustration is at the current confusion in the continuity of web3. I made this question to clarify here. There was no point in adding yet another issue on github. All of my dapps use 0.2, and so many things have changed in a year. I don't know what is best practice, but I do know that injecting web3 manually is a good idea for a lot of reasons, UX being the number one. TronWeb is in an even more confusing predicament, with a 800KB dependency for things to run. Even just a stock minified version isn't enough, I need granular solutions, and everyone needs Swarm hosting a fallback version.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Releases](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/releases) page, here's the source code: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/releases/tag/v1.0.0-beta.55

...which can be minified using your favourite minify-er tool.

Going another route, here's the NPM package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3/v/1.0.0-beta.55

Comment: There's no documentation on how to do this, and no examples in any project anywhere of beta 55 of minified web3 version for a browser. There is no dist of an unminified version either with these links. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Hi there. Yep, as per the discussion in issue [#2623](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/2623) you've linked to, there's nothing official available, so you'll need to grab the code and do it yourself, I'm afraid. It does mean that you could create a _mini_ minified version, containing only the parts of the package you know that your dapp needs, thereby reducing its footprint even further.

Comment: Do you know of a guide to do this? It must be difficult if there isn't a single repository with beta 55 in it. I don't want to spend days figure out either. I would rather go back to 0.20, but websocket connections are required now if you are using Infura.